Как вернуть работоспособность MYSQL server on XAAMP V 3.0.3 после смены listhen port в httpd.conf
Как вернуть работоспособность MYSQL server on XAAMP V 3.0.3 после смены listhen port в httpd.conf
При просмотре netstat tcp listhening sockets. 
